# Getting a list of used libraries by a running process on Mac OS

Tags: macos, process

I need to find out what libraries a process has loaded and might use throughout it's lifetime. Is this possible and how. Or better yet, i have a library name and i need to find out what processes are using it, is this possible.

On the same note, is it possible to get notified some how when a unix process is launched and when it is quit. They would not be child processes of my process, i just need to know globally.

**Update:**

I think I didn't give enough information. I was looking for a way to find the loaded libraries a process has and I need to do it in C/C++.

Answer (score 44):

Solaris has [`pldd`](http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/tools/ptools/index.php). For Linux you can call [`ldd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) on the executable or [`pmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) on a running process or look into `/proc/PID/maps` for mapped libraries.

Comment: `pldd` was added to Linux in March 2012.  [glibc 2.15 release announcement](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7163)

Comment: For Mac OS X [`otool -L`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html) is the equivalent of `ldd`

Comment: Another option for Linux: `strace -e trace=file YOUR_COMMAND`.  Add a `-f` in case you want to follow the processes your's spawns.  Be mindful that this is going to show all file-related syscalls, not just shared objects.

Answer (score 23):

On OS X, just need to set `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES`

```
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
./your_process
```

Answer (score 12):

On Mac OS X you can use `vmmap $pid` to get a list of mapped memory regions for a process. This does show all loaded libraries (at least it works for me here on 10.7.5).

`ps -A` will give you a list of all processes, so `ps -A | grep $APPNAME` will get you your process id $pid for use with `vmmap $pid`. `lsof -p $pid` also works.

The question seems to be asking for a dynamic method from C++. You could poll with these commands and analyse the results, although you may miss fast load/unload events.

`lsof` is open source software under a BSD licence. Its source code no doubt provides some insight for how to do this from C/C++. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof

Answer (score 10):

if lsof is not installed, you can simply cat /proc/$pid/maps

you can also check on disk executables with ldd to see what libs they will open (but that doesn't show libraries opened dynamically using dlopen()).

As for monitoring new processes, you can possibly add an inotify watch on /proc to monitor the creation/destruction of new numeric only directories.

Update: inotify on /proc doesn't work, but there are apparently alternatives, see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fa.linux.kernel/browse_frm/thread/69d1357df8ef29b2?q=proc+inotify+group:fa.linux.kernel+author:al+author:viro#a10f64ea3959356a)

Answer (score 5):

you can use lsof. See the man page for more info. Another tool is `strace`. To see if a process is launched, you can use `ps -ef` piped to `grep`, or tools like `pgrep` as well. check for the return value to know if its quit or not.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the specific answer that you are looking for, but I have something close, that will perhaps get you close to what you want.   You can display the linked library of a specific binary (not process) by:

1. install xcode https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
2. execute: otool -L PATH_TO_BINARY

EXAMPLE:

```
chris$ otool -L /usr/local/bin/mtr
mtr:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 46.1.0)
```

Comment: Note that this won't necessarily find all the libraries used by a process. This won't find libraries that are dynamically loaded via code at runtime, nor will it find other libraries that are linked to by those libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying (and failing) to do this also. Look at mach_vm_read and vm_region_recurse_64. Closed-source applications like vmmap and Apple's Crash Reporter do this also using those methods, as well as open-source GDB. You might try looking there for an answer, but the source is challenging to read.