# Getting a list of used libraries by a running process (OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal

Similar to this question, but for OS X: [Getting a list of used libraries by a running process (unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184775/getting-a-list-of-used-libraries-by-a-running-process-unix)

I'd like to see which linked libraries a specific process is using for OS X. Is there a `pldd` equivalent?

Here is more info for context:
https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/863#issuecomment-15618268

Comment: for the binary you can use `otool -L <your_binary>`

Comment: Good point, `otool` is what I ended up using.