# How to find which shared library is loaded by a process on OSX?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, osx-snow-leopard, dylib, dyld

I am trying to compile and use a shared C library as a python module and I am observing that depending on the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` my code works or it crashes with a cryptic error message.

```
Jul 24 02:44:44 master 
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib  python -c 'import opengm' 
OKAY

Jul 24 02:45:41 master 
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= python -c 'import opengm' 
python(86214,0x7fff70ccdcc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff70177500: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

I have tried to manually inspect which libraries are common between `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` and `/opt/local/lib` but I have not been able to find the cause of the crash. One way to figure out the cause of the problem will be to figure out which `dylib` files do the two processes use? I was not able to figure this using `opensnoop` or `dtruss` but maybe I was using those tools wrong.

How can I figure out the cause of this crash?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site. In future, please only post your question on a single Stack Exchange site. For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247227/how-to-find-which-shared-library-is-loaded-by-a-process-on-osx).

Comment: This question seems totally on topic to me (suppose you want to debug you compilation configuration). However it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184775/getting-a-list-of-used-libraries-by-a-running-process-unix

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES` in the environment to have `dyld` print every dynamic library that it loads into the process:

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES /usr/bin/true 
dyld: loaded: /usr/bin/true
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
[ ... snip ... ]
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
$
```